# AWS: Best way to generate a thumbnail for every frame of a s3 uploaded video

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I need to process a video file, transcode it and generate a thumbnail for every frame.

It should happen every time there's a new video on a specific AWS bucket.

I found out that AWS Lambda should be the best service for that

However, it is not working as expected and I'll explain why

I've created a simple Python2.7 file using [FFVideo](https://bitbucket.org/zakhar/ffvideo/src/8ab403fc7286b66020814e8e498b0d9f605c3c5c?at=default) 
It seems that this library doesn't support Python3.

It is a nice abstraction on top of ffmpeg

To deploy the package I had run `lld` on the FFVideo shared object, and then copied everything to my project directory, as described in their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html).
Zipped it and upload to AWS Lambda

Yet it doesn't work, I keep getting errors as if the /usr/lib64/libstdc++ is missing, even after copied it to the projecct dir, also tried /usr/lib64 and /lib64

Then as a second thought I wonder if just running `ffmpeg` wouldn't be easier...
So I just copied ffmpeg to the project dir and did a simple Python script to call it.

Missing shared objects, ok, `lld` again and copied everything to the directory.

Then AWS Lambda seems to be completely broken, I can't save it anymore and it just says **"Fix errors before saving"**
But no error message, nothing

I even have attempted to write inline a simple code, but now AWS Lambda don't even open the online editor.
I also tried to remove all the shared objects I have added, returning to the original state, but still same generic error.
Same thing if I just create a new lambda function with same old code.

Doesn't matter what I do it never even enable the Save button anymore.
I thought it might be just some AWS unstability, but it been a while.

I've looked to a [similar project](https://github.com/russmatney/lambda-pngs-to-mp4) using Node
and it doesn't seem to include anything except ffmpeg

My other idea is to use SQS to trigger a python script somewhere else to create the thumbnails

Any idea how is the best approach for that?